# How I add a CSS class to first element of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, css

I am trying to select some images from mysql and need to store result in an array.

This is my WHILE loop so far:

```
// Fetch all the records:
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $result  = "<div class='item'>\n";
        $result .= "    <div class='gallery_image'>\n";
        $result .= "        <a class='thumbnail lightbox' title='{$db_restaurant_name}' rel='gal' target='_blank' href='{$image_path}{$image}'>\n";
        $result .= "            <div class='img-holder' style='background-image:url({$image_path}{$image})'></div>\n";
        $result .= "        </a>\n";
        $result .= "    </div>\n";
        $result .= "</div>\n";  
        $gallery[] = $result;   
    }  
}
```

My question is, I want to add a `CSS` class named `active` to first element of this `$gallery` array. This class need to be add to this line `<div class='item'>\n";` Like this `class="item active"`

**UPDATE:**

```
$count = 0; 
// Fetch all the records:
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if($image_type == 0) {
        $class = '';
        if($count === 0) {
            $class = ' active';
        }

        $result  = "<div class='item {$class}'>\n";
        $result .= "    <div class='gallery_image'>\n";
        $result .= "        <a class='thumbnail lightbox' title='{$db_restaurant_name}' rel='gal' target='_blank' href='{$image_path}{$image}'>\n";
        $result .= "            <div class='img-holder' style='background-image:url({$image_path}{$image})'></div>\n";
        $result .= "        </a>\n";
        $result .= "    </div>\n";
        $result .= "</div>\n";  
        $gallery[] = $result;   

    }
    $count++;       
}
```

Can anybody tell me how I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: @Jessica, In my case, I can not use CSS. Thats why I am looking for solution in PHP

Comment: Ugly way is to keep the count of loop. Since, it's an ugly way, I won't even try to right the answer. Are you getting the index or some value from database which says that gallery row is active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a counter variable:

```
$count = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $class = '';
    if($count === 0) {
        $class = ' active';
    }
    $result  = "<div class='item" . $class . "'>\n";
    $result .= "    <div class='gallery_image'>\n";
    $result .= "        <a class='' title='' href='{$image_path}{$image}'>\n";
    $result .= "            <div class='' style='background-image:url({$image_path}{$image})'></div>\n";
    $result .= "        </a>\n";
    $result .= "    </div>\n";
    $result .= "</div>\n";  
    $gallery[] = $result;  
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: this add active class to all elements

Comment: Did you notice the "$count++;" at the end?

Comment: $count is increased inside the loop? Then it should be 0 only the first time the loop is entered. $class is reset to an empty string everytime, so it is impossible that all elements get the active class.

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a counter variable like :

```
$i = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $result  = "<div class='item " . (0 == $i ? "active" : "") . "'>\n";
    // ...
    $i ++;
}
```